# Generate thumbnails for only the first frame of animated gif with mogrify

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

How to modify this code so `mogrify` will generate thumbnails only for the first frame of animated gifs?:

```
mogrify -resize 80x80 -background white -gravity center -extent 80x80 -format jpg -quality 75 -path thumbnails *.gif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The select frame notation would be `[N]` immediately after the filename; where `N` is the frame number you wish to select. See *[Selecting Frames](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)* section under the input filename examples.

```sh
mogrify -resize 80x80 \
        -background white \
        -gravity center \
        -extent 80x80 \
        -format jpg \
        -quality 75 \
        -path thumbnails \
        *.gif[0]
```